# Forwarding email for an entire domain

Tags: email

I recently acquired the .com of my company name; previously been using .net domain.

I don’t want to switch emails from  .net, is it possible to setup anything at my .com to forward to my .net transparently?

I.E. somebody emails sales@mycompany.com and it forwards the message to sales@mycompany.net keeping the original sender name and address.

Comment: This would depend on how you host your mail. Your mail host should have an option to add an alias domain. If you added your .com as an alias, all mail sent to that domain will also arrive to your .net domain.

Answer (score 1):

depending of the registar and where your email server is you can. For example Ionos (ex 1and1) allow user to redirect any un-existing email to another email. This is done with the wildcard *@yourdomainname.ext